# Do I need an orchestration tool to autoscale/scale on demand my web service?

Tags: docker, culture, autoscaling

I have a stateless web service running in a Docker container. The web service is single threaded.

We would like to span new instances of the service when the load reaches a given threshold. Is that a job for an orchestration tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. And there are tools out there covering this piece of functionality.

Probably the most popular one is [kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/) (see also [kubernetes](/questions/tagged/kubernetes)):

> [Kubernetes (k8s)](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/what-is-kubernetes/) is an open-source system for automating
>   deployment, scaling, and management of containerized applications.

Depending on the provider for your deployment environment the actual orchestration tool/service may be already included and all you'd provide would be your desired scalability configuration. For example when deploying on the Google App Engine Flexible environment the [service scaling settings](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/reference/app-yaml#services) could look like this:

> ```
> automatic_scaling:
>   min_num_instances: 1
>   max_num_instances: 15
>   cool_down_period_sec: 180
>   cpu_utilization:
>     target_utilization: 0.6
> ```